# Moving ASP.NET MVC Register view to jQuery Dialog - missing Antiforgery token?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog, antiforgerytoken

I'm pretty new to MVC and for a project I'd like to use the existing Register functionality from the **Internet Application** template, except move it into a jQuery Modal Dialog popup.

Here is the click event of my "new user" button, I got the idea from the answer on [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443337/jquery-mvc3-submitting-a-partial-view-form-within-a-modal-dialog):

```
$("#new-user").click(function () {

   $("#dialog-modal").empty(); // clear it out first
   $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
      height: 600,
      width: 500,
      title: "New User",
      modal: true,
      open: function (event, ui) {
         $(this).load("@Url.Action("Register")");
      },
      buttons: {
         "Add New User": function (e) {
            var $this = this;
            var form = $('form', $this);

            $.post("Account/Register", JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject()), 
               function () {
                  $($this).dialog("close");
            });
          }
      }
   });
});
```

The `Url.Action` method looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
   return View("_Register");
}
```

And my **_Register.cshtml** View, which is basically a copy of the one from the template:

```
@model MyProject.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DisplayName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DisplayName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Now, when my "Add New User" button is clicked, you'll see I'm posting the form back to **Account/Register** which is the built in Action Method for the Internet Application template. That hasn't been changed at all and still is decorated with:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

However, any time I click "Add New User" and the form is posted, I get the following 500 error message (seen in Fiddler):

> The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present

I'm not sure why it isn't present because 1) my **Register.cshtml** View still contains `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and 2) if I step into that Javascript and look at the value of `JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject()`, I see:

> "{"__RequestVerificationToken":"X3APKURbjYGUYqY2qg1VdbYl50eVNzd7TJLYKCGC-awgkK7iNH_W6bVOw7C8zHDlygP0rVO2K4TLn5KE9CYsQN8VN1DbOOV0KzMGT7xso3o1","UserName":"theUserName","Password":"thePassword","ConfirmPassword":"thePassword","DisplayName":"theDisplayName","Email":"theEmail"}"

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `JSON.stringify` on a form that's already been `.serialized()`? You should just be able to pass the serialized result as a parameter to the AJAX request.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't sure about that either, I got it from that answer I linked to. The result looks valid, though. Should I remove the `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: Except that now instead of multiple parameters being sent, you're only receiving in one big string. like `"{x:1,y:2}"` is one string parameter, where as `{x:1,y:2}` is now two numeric parameters.

Comment: Wow, that's freaking all it was! Taking `JSON.stringify` out fixed it and now it works. Feel free to post that as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on our chat*

`$(form).serialize()` takes the form's controls and turns them in to a JavaScript object. then, but calling `JSON.stringify` you're wrapping the entire object in to a string. So now, a potential payload of the following:

```
{
  "__RequestVerificationToken": "X3APKURbjYGUYqY2qg1VdbYl50eVNzd7TJLYKCGC-awgkK7iNH_W6bVOw7C8zHDlygP0rVO2K4TLn5KE9CYsQN8VN1DbOOV0KzMGT7xso3o1",
  "UserName": "theUserName",
  "Password": "thePassword",
  "ConfirmPassword": "thePassword",
  "DisplayName": "theDisplayName",
  "Email": "theEmail"
}
```

Which would be received in as 6 separate parameters is now wrapped in one big string, which is only 1 parameter now.

Advice? Remove the `JSON.stringify` and just the AJAX call pass off as normal. Then `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` can see the `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter come in instead of being masked as a string.